# The official code for Nexus6, Camera and MediaPlayer can not work

Tags: android, camera, android-source

I got a Nexus6, and I download the source code(android-5.0.1_r1) and binary drivers from official Git repository.

I build the code with lunch "aosp_shamu-userdebug" option and flash the device with command "fastboot -w flashall -p shamu". BUT, when the device started again, I found it can not play any videos(only the voice but no pictures on screen), can not record any videos.

Does anyone have met this problem? or some know how to fix this problem. Thanks in advance!

---

I have added some log in some related cpp files. and the log print by logcat is below.

(the content of log is the operation that when I taped the button"record" in official Camera Application of Android Lollipop.)

```
I/CAM_VideoModule( 2047): startVideoRecording: Thread[main,5,main]
I/CAM_VideoModule( 2047): initializeRecorder: Thread[main,5,main]
W/StagefrightRecorder(  356): Max file duration is not positive: 0 us. Disabling duration limit.
W/StagefrightRecorder(  356): Target duration (0 us) too short to be respected
I/MediaFocusControl(  817):  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@33730af4
I/OMX-VENC(  356): Component_init : OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc : return = 0x0
E/OMXNodeInstance(  356): getParameter(100663311) ERROR: 0x8000100e
W/ACodec  (  356): do not know color format 0x7fa30c04 = 2141391876
W/ACodec  (  356): do not know color format 0x7f000789 = 2130708361
E/OMXNodeInstance(  356): getParameter(100663297) ERROR: 0x8000100e
I/OMX-VENC(  356): Component Deinit
I/OMX-VENC(  356): Component_init : OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc : return = 0x0
E/OMX-VENC(  356): set_parameter: metamode is valid for input port only
E/OMXNodeInstance(  356): OMX_SetParameter() failed for StoreMetaDataInBuffers: 0x8000101a
E/ACodec  (  356): [OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc] storeMetaDataInBuffers (output) failed w/ err -2147483648
W/ACodec  (  356): do not know color format 0x7fa30c04 = 2141391876
W/ACodec  (  356): do not know color format 0x7f000789 = 2130708361
I/ACodec  (  356): setupVideoEncoder succeeded
W/ACodec  (  356): do not know color format 0x7f000789 = 2130708361
I/AudioFlinger(  356): AudioFlinger's thread 0xb1619000 ready to run
W/AudioFlinger(  356): acquireAudioSessionId() unknown client 2047 for session 23
W/MPEG4Writer(  356): 32-bit file size limit (27564707712 bytes) too big. It is changed to 4294967295 bytes
I/MPEG4Writer(  356): limits: 4294967295/0 bytes/us, bit rate: 12096000 bps and the estimated moov size 405000 bytes
I/MPEG4Writer(  356): Start time offset: 1000000 us
I/MediaCodecSource(  356): MediaCodecSource (video) starting
D/NuPlayerDriver(  356): seekTo(0xb60e7b80) 0 ms
D/NuPlayerDriver(  356): start(0xb60e7b80)
I/GenericSource(  356): start
W/AudioFlinger(  356): acquireAudioSessionId() unknown client 2047 for session 22
D/audio_hw_primary(  356): out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=2
D/audio_hw_primary(  356): select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: none)
D/msm8974_platform(  356): platform_send_audio_calibration: sending audio calibration for snd_device(2) acdb_id(15)
E/ACDB-LOADER(  356): Error: ACDB AFE returned = -19
D/audio_hw_primary(  356): enable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
D/audio_hw_primary(  356): enable_audio_route: apply and update mixer path: low-latency-playback speaker
E/Camera3-Stream(  356): ############## Camera3Stream::Camera3Stream
E/Camera3-OutputStream(  356): ########## usage:256(0x100)
E/Camera3-OutputStream(  356): ########## usage:3(0x3)
E/Camera3-OutputStream(  356): ########## usage:65536(0x10000)
E/mm-camera-intf(  356): mm_camera_poll_thread_del_poll_fd: invalid handler 1792 (0)
I/mm-camera(  372): mct_pipeline_process_set:command=8000009
I/mm-camera(  372): mct_pipeline_process_set: stream_type = 1, streamid 2
I/mm-camera-sensor(  372): module_sensor_module_process_event:3884 ide 20002 MCT_EVENT_CONTROL_STREAMOFF
E/mm-camera(  372): c2d_module_handle_streamoff_event:1411, info: doing stream-off for identity 0x20002
E/mm-camera-img(  372): faceproc_save_album: cannot open file name: /data/camera/fdAlbum
E/mm-camera(  372): c2d_module_handle_streamoff_event:1486, info: stream-off done for identity 0x20002
E/mm-camera(  372): cpp_module_handle_streamoff_event:3473] iden:0x20002, linked_params:0x0
E/mm-camera(  372): cpp_hardware_process_streamoff:676] skip_iden:0x0, duplicate_stream_status:0x0
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_streamoff_to_thread: E, session id = 2, user stream id = 2
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_streamoff: E, session_id 2 mct_stream_id = 2
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_util_decide_hw_streams: num_user_streams 1 num_hw_streams 1
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_ispif_streamoff: Enter
I/mm-camera(  372): iface_ispif_streamoff: config hw_stream id = 10002 use_pix 1, vfe_intf_mask 10000, axi_path 1, num_cid 1
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_ispif_streamoff: hw stream 10002 does not use vfe0 interface
I/mm-camera(  372): iface_ispif_streamoff: config VFE1 for hw stream id 10002
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_ispif_streamoff: interface 0 still active,skip streamoff hw stream id 10002
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_ispif_streamoff: X, rc = 0
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_util_release_image_buf:5169 <kmdebug> stream_id: 2 hw_stream_id: 0x10002 buf_handle: 0x90008 buff_id: 0
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_streamoff: session_id = 2, active_streams = 1
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_streamoff: all bundled stream streamoff, clear hal bundled mask
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_streamoff: X
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_streamoff_to_thread: X, session id = 2, user stream id = 2
I/mm-camera-sensor(  372): module_sensor_is_ready_for_stream_off:1325 any bundle started 0
I/mm-camera(  372): mct_pipeline_process_set: Stream on/off returned
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera-intf(  356): mm_camera_poll_thread_del_poll_fd: invalid handler 2304 (0)
I/mm-camera(  372): mct_pipeline_process_set:command=8000009
I/mm-camera(  372): mct_pipeline_process_set: stream_type = 3, streamid 3
I/mm-camera-sensor(  372): module_sensor_module_process_event:3884 ide 20003 MCT_EVENT_CONTROL_STREAMOFF
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): linearization40_trigger_update:1192 failed: linearization40_select_table
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_sub_module_port_isp_private_event:286 failed: module linearization40 private event 4
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_sub_module_port_process_downstream_module_event:1090 failed: mct event 56 int event 13
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): chroma_enhan40_trigger_update_awb:1294 failed: mod->color_temp = 0, return FALSE!
E/mm-camera(  372): stats_port_event stop sending AEC_UPDATE
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_axi_proc_subdev_event: enforce queue back stats buf!rc = 0, piggy back flag 1
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_axi_proc_subdev_event: queue back stats buffer, i = 8, buf idx = 0
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_axi_proc_subdev_event: queue back stats buffer, i = 11, buf idx = 0
E/mm-camera-CORE(  372): aec_process_pack_stats_config invalid inputs to translate dimensions for  fov 2 camif 
E/mm-camera(  372): stats_port_event stop sending AEC_UPDATE
E/mm-camera(  372): stats_port_event stop sending AWB_UPDATE
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_streamoff_to_thread: E, session id = 2, user stream id = 3
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_ispif_streamoff: Enter
I/mm-camera(  372): iface_ispif_streamoff: config hw_stream id = 3 use_pix 1, vfe_intf_mask 10000, axi_path 0, num_cid 1
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_ispif_streamoff: hw stream 3 does not use vfe0 interface
I/mm-camera(  372): iface_ispif_streamoff: config VFE1 for hw stream id 3
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_ispif_streamoff: X, rc = 0
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_util_release_image_buf:5169 <kmdebug> stream_id: 3 hw_stream_id: 0x3 buf_handle: 0xa0009 buff_id: 0
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_streamoff: session_id = 2, active_streams = 0
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_util_subscribe_sof_event: subscribe sof, used resource 10000
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_stats_unreg_buf: last VFE close, relase stats buffer
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_axi_stats_stream_unconfig: release stats stream id 80010003, handle 505
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_stats_unreg_buf: last VFE close, relase stats buffer
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_axi_stats_stream_unconfig: release stats stream id 80010004, handle 606
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_stats_unreg_buf: last VFE close, relase stats buffer
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_axi_stats_stream_unconfig: release stats stream id 80010005, handle 807
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_stats_unreg_buf: last VFE close, relase stats buffer
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_axi_stats_stream_unconfig: release stats stream id 80010007, handle 302
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_stats_unreg_buf: last VFE close, relase stats buffer
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_axi_stats_stream_unconfig: release stats stream id 80010008, handle 203
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_stats_unreg_buf: last VFE close, relase stats buffer
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_axi_stats_stream_unconfig: release stats stream id 80010009, handle 401
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_stats_unreg_buf: last VFE close, relase stats buffer
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_axi_stats_stream_unconfig: release stats stream id 8001000a, handle 708
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_stats_unreg_buf: last VFE close, relase stats buffer
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_axi_stats_stream_unconfig: release stats stream id 8001000b, handle 900
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_util_release_resource: camif_cnt= 1 rdi_cnt= 0 used mask 10000
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_util_release_resource: camif_cnt= 0 rdi_cnt= 0 used mask 0
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_streamoff: all bundled stream streamoff, clear hal bundled mask
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_streamoff: X
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_streamoff_to_thread: X, session id = 2, user stream id = 3
I/mm-camera-sensor(  372): module_sensor_is_ready_for_stream_off:1325 any bundle started 0
I/mm-camera-sensor(  372): module_sensor_module_process_event:3904 ide 20003 MCT_EVENT_CONTROL_STREAMOFF
E/mm-camera-sensor(  372): module_sensor_module_process_event: Sending stop bus message
E/mm-camera(  372): stop_sof_check_thread: Stopping SOF timeout thread
I/mm-camera(  372): mct_pipeline_process_set: Stream on/off returned
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
I/mm-camera(  372): mct_pipeline_process_set:command=8000009
I/mm-camera(  372): mct_pipeline_process_set: stream_type = 7, streamid 1
I/mm-camera(  372): mct_pipeline_process_set: Stream on/off returned
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_metadata_ctrl_event:2417: ret=1 Unsupported cmd
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_metadata_ctrl_event:2417: ret=1 Unsupported cmd
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_metadata_ctrl_event:2417: ret=1 Unsupported cmd
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_metadata_ctrl_event:2417: ret=1 Unsupported cmd
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_metadata_ctrl_event:2417: ret=1 Unsupported cmd
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_metadata_ctrl_event:2417: ret=1 Unsupported cmd
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_metadata_ctrl_event:2417: ret=1 Unsupported cmd
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_metadata_ctrl_event:2417: ret=1 Unsupported cmd
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_metadata_ctrl_event:2417: ret=1 Unsupported cmd
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_metadata_ctrl_event:2417: ret=1 Unsupported cmd
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_metadata_ctrl_event:2417: ret=1 Unsupported cmd
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_metadata_ctrl_event:2417: ret=1 Unsupported cmd
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_metadata_ctrl_event:2417: ret=1 Unsupported cmd
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_metadata_ctrl_event:2417: ret=1 Unsupported cmd
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_metadata_ctrl_event:2417: ret=1 Unsupported cmd
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_metadata_ctrl_event:2417: ret=1 Unsupported cmd
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_metadata_ctrl_event:2417: ret=1 Unsupported cmd
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_metadata_ctrl_event:2417: ret=1 Unsupported cmd
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit 
I/mm-camera(  372): mct_pipeline_process_set:command=800000b
I/mm-camera(  372): mct_pipeline_process_set: stream_type = 1, streamid 2
I/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy: Destroying stream [0x20002] of type 1
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_streamoff: Enter
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_streamoff: Enter
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_streamoff: Enter
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_streamoff: Enter
I/mm-camera-sensor(  372): port_sensor_unlink_func:232 ide 20002
I/mm-camera-sensor(  372): port_sensor_caps_unreserve:201 ide 20002
I/mm-camera(  372): port_iface_check_caps_unreserve_func:  E, identity = 0x20002, port = 0xb6a51340, direction = 2
I/mm-camera(  372): port_iface_check_caps_unreserve_func: X, rc = 1, identity = 0x20002, port = 0xb6a51340, direction = 2
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_ext_unlink_src_port: mct stream already removed from hw stream
I/mm-camera(  372): port_iface_check_caps_unreserve_func:  E, identity = 0x20002, port = 0xb6a51640, direction = 1
I/mm-camera(  372): port_iface_check_caps_unreserve_func: X, rc = 1, identity = 0x20002, port = 0xb6a51640, direction = 1
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_port_check_caps_unreserve:807 ide 20002 port 0xb684bd60
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1327 type 1
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1363 vfe 1 isp_submod_ports 0xb6848400 port parent linearization40
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1371 unlink linearization40 mesh_rolloff44
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1371 unlink mesh_rolloff44 demux40
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1371 unlink demux40 demosaic44
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1371 unlink demosaic44 bf_stats44
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1371 unlink bf_stats44 bf_scale_stats44
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1371 unlink bf_scale_stats44 bg_stats44
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1371 unlink bg_stats44 be_stats44
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1371 unlink be_stats44 rs_stats44
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1371 unlink rs_stats44 cs_stats44
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1371 unlink cs_stats44 ihist_stats44
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1371 unlink ihist_stats44 bhist_stats44
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1371 unlink bhist_stats44 chroma_enhan40
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1371 unlink chroma_enhan40 bpc44
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1371 unlink bpc44 bcc44
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1371 unlink bcc44 abf44
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1371 unlink abf44 color_correct40
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1371 unlink color_correct40 luma_adaptation40
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1371 unlink luma_adaptation40 mce40
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1371 unlink mce40 sce40
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1371 unlink sce40 clf44
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1371 unlink clf44 wb40
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1371 unlink wb40 gamma44
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1371 unlink gamma44 ltm44
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1400 unlink ltm44 color_xform_viewfinder40
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1400 unlink color_xform_viewfinder40 scaler_viewfinder44
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1400 unlink scaler_viewfinder44 fovcrop_viewfinder40
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1400 unlink fovcrop_viewfinder40 clamp_viewfinder40
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_port_check_caps_unreserve:807 ide 20002 port 0xb684be80
I/mm-camera(  372): pproc_port_sink_check_caps_unreserve:1174] E
E/mm-camera(  372): module_afs_port_check_caps_unreserve:1335] E
E/mm-camera(  372): module_afs_port_check_caps_unreserve:1373] 
E/mm-camera(  372): module_afs_port_check_caps_unreserve:1381] destroy client
E/mm-camera(  372): module_afs_port_check_caps_unreserve:1388] X
E/mm-camera(  372): module_afs_port_check_caps_unreserve:1335] E
E/mm-camera(  372): module_afs_port_check_caps_unreserve:1388] X
E/mm-camera(  372): module_cac_port_check_caps_unreserve:1206] E port cac_d2_i2, identity 0x20002, dir 2
E/mm-camera(  372): module_cac_port_check_caps_unreserve:1236] X
E/mm-camera(  372): module_cac_port_check_caps_unreserve:1206] E port cac_d1_i2, identity 0x20002, dir 1
E/mm-camera(  372): module_cac_port_check_caps_unreserve:1236] X
E/mm-camera(  372): c2d_port_check_caps_unreserve:164, identity=0x20002
E/mm-camera(  372): c2d_port_check_caps_unreserve:174, identity=0x20002, unreserved
I/mm-camera(  372): pproc_port_sink_check_caps_unreserve:1227] X rc: 1
E/mm-camera(  372): c2d_port_check_caps_unreserve:164, identity=0x20002
E/mm-camera(  372): c2d_port_check_caps_unreserve:174, identity=0x20002, unreserved
E/mm-camera(  372): module_faceproc_port_check_caps_unreserve:1420] E id 20002
E/mm-camera(  372): module_faceproc_port_check_caps_unreserve:1504] ref_cnt 0 1 mask 0 X
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_port_check_caps_unreserve:807 ide 20002 port 0xb684bee0
I/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy: Stream [0x20002] destroyed successfully
E/QCamera3Channel(  356): virtual qcamera::QCamera3Channel::~QCamera3Channel(): deleting channel 1537
E/QCamera3Channel(  356): virtual int32_t qcamera::QCamera3PicChannel::stop(): Attempt to stop inactive channel
I/qomx_image_core(  356): OMX_Deinit:118] Complete
I/mm-camera(  372): mct_pipeline_process_set:command=800000b
I/mm-camera(  372): mct_pipeline_process_set: stream_type = 3, streamid 3
I/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_destroy: Destroying stream [0x20003] of type 3
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_streamoff: Enter
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_streamoff: Enter
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_stream_streamoff: Enter
I/mm-camera-sensor(  372): port_sensor_unlink_func:232 ide 20003
I/mm-camera-sensor(  372): port_sensor_caps_unreserve:201 ide 20003
I/mm-camera(  372): port_iface_check_caps_unreserve_func:  E, identity = 0x20003, port = 0xb6a51340, direction = 2
I/mm-camera(  372): port_iface_check_caps_unreserve_func: X, rc = 1, identity = 0x20003, port = 0xb6a51340, direction = 2
E/mm-camera(  372): iface_ext_unlink_src_port: mct stream already removed from hw stream
I/mm-camera(  372): port_iface_check_caps_unreserve_func:  E, identity = 0x20003, port = 0xb6a51640, direction = 1
I/mm-camera(  372): port_iface_check_caps_unreserve_func: X, rc = 1, identity = 0x20003, port = 0xb6a51640, direction = 1
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_port_check_caps_unreserve:807 ide 20003 port 0xb684bd60
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1327 type 3
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1363 vfe 1 isp_submod_ports 0xb6848400 port parent linearization40
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1371 unlink linearization40 mesh_rolloff44
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1371 unlink mesh_rolloff44 demux40
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1400 unlink ltm44 color_xform_viewfinder40
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1400 unlink color_xform_viewfinder40 scaler_viewfinder44
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1400 unlink scaler_viewfinder44 fovcrop_viewfinder40
E/mm-camera-isp2(  372): isp_resource_unlink_modules:1400 unlink fovcrop_viewfinder40 clamp_viewfinder40
I/mm-jpeg-intf(  356): Max picture size 4160 x 3120, WorkBufSize = 19568640
I/qomx_image_core(  356): OMX_Init:94] Complete 2
E/mm-camera(  372): mct_pipeline_get_stream: stream not found in the list
I/mm-camera(  372): mct_pipeline_process_set: Couldn't find preview stream; Storing for later
E/Camera3-OutputStream(  356): ###########  usage1 :131106(0x20022)
E/Camera3-OutputStream(  356): #### res : 0   mMaxSize:0
E/Camera3-OutputStream(  356): ########  res2:0  c3-stream::format:34
E/Camera3-OutputStream(  356): ########### mTotalBufferCount:15
E/Camera3-OutputStream(  356): ############ return OK!
D/Camera3-Stream(  356): registerBuffersLocked: Skipping NULL check for deprecated register_stream_buffers
W/qdgralloc(  247):  USAGE : GRALLOC_USAGE_HW_VIDEO_ENCODER(65536) GRALLOC_USAGE_HW_CAMERA_MASK(393216) GRALLOC_USAGE_HW_CAMERA_READ(262144) GRALLOC_USAGE_HW_CAMERA_WRITE(131072) GRALLOC_USAGE_HW_COMPOSER(2048)
W/qdgralloc(  247): FORMAT : HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_IMPLEMENTATION_DEFINED(34) HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YCbCr_420_888(35) HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_NV12_ENCODEABLE(258) HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_NV21_ZSL(275)             HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YCrCb_420_SP(17) HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YCrCb_420_SP(17) HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888(1)
I/MediaCodecSource(  356): MediaCodecSource (video) started
W/qdgralloc(  247): >>>>>>>>>>> alloc_impl 3   w:1280 h:720 format:34 usage:196642(30022) stride:0  grallocFormat:258
W/qdgralloc(  247): >>>>>>>>>>>> alloc_impl 3.5
E/qdmemalloc(  247): @@@@@ format:258(0x102)   HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_sRGB_X_8888(13)   [HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB_888:3] [HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB_565:4]
E/qdmemalloc(  247): ::::: getSize => format : 258(0x102)
E/qdmemalloc(  247): ::::: case 10
W/qdgralloc(  247): >>>>>>>>>>>>   size :0    alignedw:0  alignedh:0
W/GraphicBufferAllocator(  247): alloc(1280, 720, 34, 00030022, ...) failed -22 (Invalid argument)
E/        (  247): GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer(w=1280, h=720) failed (Invalid argument), handle=0x0
I/MPEG4Writer(  356): Start time offset: 1000000 us
E/BufferQueueProducer(  356): [Camera2-RecordingConsumer] dequeueBuffer: createGraphicBuffer failed
E/Camera3-OutputStream(  356): getBufferLocked: Stream 2: Can't dequeue next output buffer: Invalid argument (-22)
I/MediaCodecSource(  356): MediaCodecSource (audio) starting
E/Camera3-Device(  356): RequestThread: Can't get output buffer, skipping request: Invalid argument (-22)
E/Camera2ClientBase(  356): Error condition 3 reported by HAL, requestId 20000010
W/qdgralloc(  247):  USAGE : GRALLOC_USAGE_HW_VIDEO_ENCODER(65536) GRALLOC_USAGE_HW_CAMERA_MASK(393216) GRALLOC_USAGE_HW_CAMERA_READ(262144) GRALLOC_USAGE_HW_CAMERA_WRITE(131072) GRALLOC_USAGE_HW_COMPOSER(2048)
W/qdgralloc(  247): FORMAT : HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_IMPLEMENTATION_DEFINED(34) HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YCbCr_420_888(35) HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_NV12_ENCODEABLE(258) HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_NV21_ZSL(275)             HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YCrCb_420_SP(17) HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YCrCb_420_SP(17) HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888(1)
W/qdgralloc(  247): >>>>>>>>>>> alloc_impl 3   w:1280 h:720 format:34 usage:196642(30022) stride:0  grallocFormat:258
W/qdgralloc(  247): >>>>>>>>>>>> alloc_impl 3.5
E/qdmemalloc(  247): @@@@@ format:258(0x102)   HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_sRGB_X_8888(13)   [HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB_888:3] [HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB_565:4]
E/qdmemalloc(  247): ::::: getSize => format : 258(0x102)
E/qdmemalloc(  247): ::::: case 10
W/qdgralloc(  247): >>>>>>>>>>>>   size :0    alignedw:0  alignedh:0
W/GraphicBufferAllocator(  247): alloc(1280, 720, 34, 00030022, ...) failed -22 (Invalid argument)
E/        (  247): GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer(w=1280, h=720) failed (Invalid argument), handle=0x0
E/BufferQueueProducer(  356): [Camera2-RecordingConsumer] dequeueBuffer: createGraphicBuffer failed
E/Camera3-OutputStream(  356): getBufferLocked: Stream 2: Can't dequeue next output buffer: Invalid argument (-22)
E/Camera3-Device(  356): RequestThread: Can't get output buffer, skipping request: Invalid argument (-22)
E/Camera2ClientBase(  356): Error condition 3 reported by HAL, requestId 20000010
I/SoundTriggerHwService::Module(  356): void android::SoundTriggerHwService::Module::onCallbackEvent(const android::sp<android::SoundTriggerHwService::CallbackEvent>&) mClient == 0
W/qdgralloc(  247):  USAGE : GRALLOC_USAGE_HW_VIDEO_ENCODER(65536) GRALLOC_USAGE_HW_CAMERA_MASK(393216) GRALLOC_USAGE_HW_CAMERA_READ(262144) GRALLOC_USAGE_HW_CAMERA_WRITE(131072) GRALLOC_USAGE_HW_COMPOSER(2048)
W/qdgralloc(  247): FORMAT : HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_IMPLEMENTATION_DEFINED(34) HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YCbCr_420_888(35) HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_NV12_ENCODEABLE(258) HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_NV21_ZSL(275)             HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YCrCb_420_SP(17) HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YCrCb_420_SP(17) HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888(1)
W/qdgralloc(  247): >>>>>>>>>>> alloc_impl 3   w:1280 h:720 format:34 usage:196642(30022) stride:0  grallocFormat:258
W/qdgralloc(  247): >>>>>>>>>>>> alloc_impl 3.5
E/qdmemalloc(  247): @@@@@ format:258(0x102)   HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_sRGB_X_8888(13)   [HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB_888:3] [HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB_565:4]
E/qdmemalloc(  247): ::::: getSize => format : 258(0x102)
E/qdmemalloc(  247): ::::: case 10
W/qdgralloc(  247): >>>>>>>>>>>>   size :0    alignedw:0  alignedh:0
W/GraphicBufferAllocator(  247): alloc(1280, 720, 34, 00030022, ...) failed -22 (Invalid argument)
E/        (  247): GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer(w=1280, h=720) failed (Invalid argument), handle=0x0
E/BufferQueueProducer(  356): [Camera2-RecordingConsumer] dequeueBuffer: createGraphicBuffer failed
E/Camera3-OutputStream(  356): getBufferLocked: Stream 2: Can't dequeue next output buffer: Invalid argument (-22)
E/Camera3-Device(  356): RequestThread: Can't get output buffer, skipping request: Invalid argument (-22)
E/Camera2ClientBase(  356): Error condition 3 reported by HAL, requestId 20000010
W/qdgralloc(  247):  USAGE : GRALLOC_USAGE_HW_VIDEO_ENCODER(65536) GRALLOC_USAGE_HW_CAMERA_MASK(393216) GRALLOC_USAGE_HW_CAMERA_READ(262144) GRALLOC_USAGE_HW_CAMERA_WRITE(131072) GRALLOC_USAGE_HW_COMPOSER(2048)
W/qdgralloc(  247): FORMAT : HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_IMPLEMENTATION_DEFINED(34) HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YCbCr_420_888(35) HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_NV12_ENCODEABLE(258) HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_NV21_ZSL(275)             HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YCrCb_420_SP(17) HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YCrCb_420_SP(17) HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888(1)
W/qdgralloc(  247): >>>>>>>>>>> alloc_impl 3   w:1280 h:720 format:34 usage:196642(30022) stride:0  grallocFormat:258
W/qdgralloc(  247): >>>>>>>>>>>> alloc_impl 3.5
E/qdmemalloc(  247): @@@@@ format:258(0x102)   HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_sRGB_X_8888(13)   [HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB_888:3] [HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB_565:4]
E/qdmemalloc(  247): ::::: getSize => format : 258(0x102)
E/qdmemalloc(  247): ::::: case 10
W/qdgralloc(  247): >>>>>>>>>>>>   size :0    alignedw:0  alignedh:0
W/GraphicBufferAllocator(  247): alloc(1280, 720, 34, 00030022, ...) failed -22 (Invalid argument)
E/        (  247): GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer(w=1280, h=720) failed (Invalid argument), handle=0x0
E/BufferQueueProducer(  356): [Camera2-RecordingConsumer] dequeueBuffer: createGraphicBuffer failed
E/Camera3-OutputStream(  356): getBufferLocked: Stream 2: Can't dequeue next output buffer: Invalid argument (-22)
E/Camera3-Device(  356): RequestThread: Can't get output buffer, skipping request: Invalid argument (-22)
E/Camera2ClientBase(  356): Error condition 3 reported by HAL, requestId 20000010
```

Comment: **Version of driver is LRX22C**

Comment: I have Nexus 6 too, it updated to 5.0.1 automatically. Build number LRX22C

Comment: Have you tried to flash your device by official 5.0 code ?

Comment: AOSP code never works as-is. Did you download the right vendor files?

Comment: yes, I download the vendor files LRX22C and LRX210, both of them did not work, can not play mp4 video and record video by its camera. the logcat says "E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(  351): Extension: OMX.google.android.index.describeColorFormat not implemented" when it play videos. I will upload another log later.

Comment: And another log of playing mp4 videos as below:

http://88.80.191.145/logs/nexus6_can_not_play_mp4.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can try from source code on GitHub [Camera2](http://github.com/pinguo-yuyidong/Camera2) by pinguo-yuyidong.